# UML Sequence Diagram: System returns a list

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I'm doing an SSD between a user and a youtube like system, and I have a method where the user asks the system to show the playlist: showPlaylist()

The system returns a list of every video on the playlist and also each video's run time.

I'm having trouble representing this. I'm not returning multiple attributes of one single video, I'm returning a list of videos and specifying which of its atributtes I show.

I tought about doing a loop where it returns run times but I don't know what the exit condition would be.

Or am I overthinking this and I should just return a single variable, my list?

Help is appreciated, but the text for my exercise is in portuguese and already a bit confusing so translating it all would be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's rather simple: you return a collection which is just a single object. And this is capable to hold any number of objects (your single songs). So the return value will be `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

You have few reasonable options here. Let me recommend three most appropriate ones:

1. Use a class `Video` as a return data type. Of course set multiplicity to `*`.

This gives you most flexibility but comes with most overhead.

2. Use DataType `Video` as a return data type. Again set multiplicity to `*`.

This way your return attribute is far simpler still with plenty of flexibility. If you want to make datatype reusable you may still end up with overhead.

3. Use two out attributes, both ordered with multiplicity `*`. One will hold titles, the other times. Ordering has to be the same.

Here you limit the amount of transferred information to the minimum.

This list is by no means complete. Loop is also possible (with "no more videos" or  "returned null" as exit condition) but that would be probably an inefficient overkill.